# How to query documents from a sub-collection, based on a main collection's field and a sub-collection's fields in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, geofirestore

I am new to firebase cloud firestore and need help understanding it a bit.

I am working on a project of the following structure.[image: firebase firestore collection screenshot]

[image: firebase firestore subcollection screenshot]

Each "Restaurant" document contains its own "products" subcollection.

> Here, I wanted to run a query to get all the products by different
> restaurants that contain the tag "coffee" and are in a specific
> Pincode "234144".

I tried Collection group queries by adding Pincode to each product owned by a particular restaurant but changing a Pincode would cost a lot, as all products would have to be edited, I guess.

> Is there any efficient way of doing it or is it not possible in this
> database in an efficient way?

Please let me know what do you think... Thank you.

Comment: are products shared by different restaurants?

Comment: No, each 'restaurant' document has its own 'products' collection.

Comment: I don't know why your question gets downvotes, because you pinpoint a surprising thing about Firestore data modeling. I advise you to watch the video I mention in my answer, you will see that you are not the only one surprised by this!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve all products with a certain tag and pincode (I suppose this is similar to a postal zipcode?). There really are only two alternatives that I can think of:

### Collection group query

As you mention, you can store both *tag* and *pincode* in *product* documents. Then perform a single collection group query along these lines (pardon the javascript, but I am not familiar with Dart, it should be very similar):

```
var products = await firestore.collectionGroup('products')
                       .where('tag', '==', 'coffee')
                       .where('pincode', '==', '234144').get();
```

As you have noted, with this solution you need to keep *pincode* in each *product* This piece of data is duplicated and it is normal to feel that it should be avoided because it is wasteful and dangerous (can go out of sync), but this is the way to go! It is called **denormalization**. This is well explained in [this video by Todd Kerpelman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW7DWV2jST0).
You can then create a Cloud Function triggered by *restaurant* update to keep *pincode* in *products* in sync with the corresponding *pincode* in *restaurants*

### Query restaurants then products

To keep the *pincode* in restaurants only, you have to do your query in two steps: first filter restaurants in the certain pincode, then filter products by tag:

```
// 1 - retrieve restaurants in specific pincode
var restaurants = await firestore.collection('restaurants').where('pincode', '==', '234144').get();

// 2 - For each retrieved restaurant, retrieve all products matching the tag
var products = [];
for(let i = 0; i < restaurants.docs.length; ++i) {
  var p = await restaurants.docs[i].collection("products").where("tag", "==", "coffee");
  products.push(p);
}
```

With this method, no need to duplicate *pincode* in each *product*, however your queries are less optimal, because you load potentially useless *restaurants* that do not serve coffee in your pincode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar data structure, and Louis Coulet's answer helped me a lot. However, I ran into an issue, as my node/firebase environment complained that `restaurants.docs[i].collection` was not a function. Instead, I had to use `restaurants.docs[i].ref.collection`.

So, in my case, here's the code that wound up working (using the original poster's "restaurants/products" data model as an example):

```
// 1 - retrieve restaurants in specific pincode
const restaurants = await firestore.collection('restaurants').where('pincode', '==', '234144').get();

// 2 - For each retrieved restaurant, retrieve all products matching the tag 'coffee'
const products = [];
for (let i = 0; i < restaurants.docs.length; i++) {      
    await restaurants.docs[i].ref
          .collection('products')
          .where('tag', '==', 'coffee')
          .get()
          .then(s => Promise.all(s.docs.map(d => {
              products.push(d);
          })));
}
```

I have found that I need to return the sub-collection contents via some kind of promise, otherwise, after I try to get the data in the variable -- `products`, in this case -- it just shows up as undefined.

After I populate the `products` variable, I am then able to read its contents like this:

```
products.forEach(p => {
   console.log(p.data().name);
   console.log(p.data().tag);
}
```

I hope someone finds this useful, and many, MANY thanks to Louis Coulet for sending me/us down the correct path with this sub-collection headache :-)